# app is not running in tab but running fine in phone?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-package-managers

I have downloaded some sample source codes, modified them and made a audio-video player. 
The player is supporting minimum Android version 2.2. I ran the app in my tab, as well as phone.

It's working fine for my Android phone, but not in my tab. I am not sure why this is happening. 
I am not even able to install the `.apk` file in my Android tab.

Can anybody suggest me what may be cause of this?

Comment: Are you installing through Eclipse or running the .apk on the device?

Comment: running the .apk in my device. In eclipse it's running fine. I made it as a signed application package and copy to my device. when I tried to install it I am getting the error like application can't be installed.

Comment: Try doing it whilst plugged in to your pc with the logcat running in eclipse. You might get some clues there. Is there any permissions in the manifest that might need somthing not on the device, e.g GPS or camera? What device is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to install apps from places other than the market, you need to enable that in Applications settings - **allow unknown sources**. enable it.

enable usb debugging also 
With the debug tools installed, you can install an apk from the command line by saying

```
adb install my.apk.
```

Comment: I have tried them, but still not getting. Is there any possibilities where I have made the mistakes? But the main problem is that it's working fine in certain phones.